# Basic Project imbalance?

Tags: crafting, exalted-3e

The Crafting rules in Exalted are wonky at times, and some crafts in particular seem to be made to farm silver XP from making *Basic Projects*<sup>Exalted 3rd Ed. core book [Ex3] p.239</sup>. One such example is cooking:

A mortal PC cook (let's name him [Jackie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Nice_Guy_(1997_film))) might have *Wits 5* + *Crafts (cooking) 5* and thus rolls 10 dice. He creates a bowl with one super long noodle in broth with a few pulls on his dough, then dumps then in preprepared broth<sup>(1)</sup>. the difficulty for such is trivial for heros and thus 1<sup>Ex3 p.185</sup>. He will most likely come up with a spread like "1 2 3 4 5 
 6 7 8 9 10", meaning he gets in an average roll about 5 successes whith a threshold of 4, meaning he succeeded exceptionally well. This means, Jackie will get 3 Silver XP per objective.

- Jackie has a clear in game benefit: he earns his living by this, so gets the points for it.
- Jackie likes to cook, and he likes noodles especially, so he gets the 'fulfilled an own intimacy' objective.
- Finally, a good bowl of noodles might be enough to gain or strengthen some intimacy like "I like Jackie's noodles".

That's 9 Silver XP - and he can churn out these bowls of noodles en masse because they take a trivial ammount of time and resources. That means, on a busy street corner in Nexus he might just need to work a single day and have enough Silver XP and for his lifetime never touch noodles again but cook the most exquisite stuff.

---

On the other hand, other crafts named in the book are really hard to find any such simple projects for. The most obvious ones would be Geomancy and Architecture - which are notorious for their use in Large Scale Projects<sup>Ex3 p.243</sup>.

Now I feel this bahavior of "easy, mass produceable silver XP" with the right crafts does inbalance the game between some kind of Jakie and someone that does have only these 'high' crafts but, for which no such super simple tasks exist to get the character rolling: There really is no new architecture project that would be neglectable in time and resources<sup>(1)</sup>, and geomancy likewise lacks these simple ways to get the first silver XP to get the major projects<sup>(2)</sup> started that these two mostly seem to care for.

Is this imbalance just percieved and I blatantly overlook the possible uses of Architecture/Geomancy? Or do I have a flawed understanding of the allowances/limitations on the crafting rules?

<sup>(1) - They normally demand little from the character in time
or crafting materials.</sup>
<sup>(2) - They place a significant burden on the character in terms of time, materials, or both.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top end of these crafts is similarly different...

Architecture does have some more farmable options. Practicing Architecture doesn't mean you need to actually *build* the thing...just design it.

You could design small houses for people...or doghouses, or stables, and so on. In this case, you're just coming up with and drawing a blueprint...pretty easy

Geomancy (and Artifacts) on the other hand....

Sure, it's easy to farm Silver XP on basic projects in cooking, but at the top end of cooking you're....still making a single meal that will be consumed. It will be the best meal ever but...it's still a meal.

Architecture builds mansions and fortresses that will last for ages. Geomancy builds **Manses** which are kind of a Big Deal. It's the same idea with Craft (Artifacts). It takes a lot more work to 'farm' XP up for Artifacts and Geomancy...but the final output is much more significant. A high-end Cooking project would be something like 'A fabulous banquet.' A high-end Artifact project could be a Daiklave. A high end Geomancy project creates you a Manse. Between cooking and those two...what do you figure will have a larger influence on the game overall?

So that's the difference in the balance point. Some craft are easy to 'farm' XP...others have a more spectacular top-end.

Comment: Not an *Exalted* player, but from this outsider's view it sounds like a PC may get the best results by having at least two craft skills: one short-term for farming XP and one long-term to make an impact on the campaign. Is that accurate? Is that possible? Is that typical?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That's fairly common in a dedicated crafter. Cooking is actually well favored for that.

Comment: That's cool. Can you cite a character from a printed source that seems to encourage that (our?) line of thinking, or do published characters tend to focus on a lone craft skill to the exclusion of others?